# How to find a provided value from mule in an excel file

Tags: excel, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

In my mule flow I have one value which needs to be found in an excel file and corresponding values related that value also needs to fetched.

It's some sort multiple value retrieval based on one value in mule from excel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a recent version of mule you could take advantage of [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation), in fact compared to the old datamapper it will offer why more power when coming to perform particular logic while performing the mappings.
One example that you can find on mule documentation is that you can extract record based on conditions while mapping:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
users: payload.users.name[?($ == "Mariano")]
```

IF instead you are still on older versions than with the DataMapper you don't have so many options, basically the only thing you can do is to convert all the records in another format, for example a groovy map, and then perform your search there by using a small piece of groovy or java.
In alternative you can always go to XML and use XPATH expression.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mauro.  I am new to mule and have to work on older version where I do not have DataWeave facility. Groovy is also new to me so if you can provide a sample there so that I can make progress in it. How can convert the excel data into groovy map. The sheet size is big. Will this be a good solution to convert them into groovy map.

Comment: You can use the DataMapper (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/datamapper-user-guide-and-reference) component if you use mule enterprise.
In general the excel size is not a big problem if you don't get close to the 500mb mark. If you are not familiar with groovy than just use java and I cannot provide you with an example as I don't know almost anything about your case but just note that the datamapper will convert the excel in an ArrayList of HashMap so after is just some simple java coding.